# Google Maps integration lightens text below it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

Edit: It seems to be an issue on my end, at least I wasn't able to replicate it outside of my Mac OS setup with Chrome / Safari.

I'm using Google Maps on [this site](http://garten-moorriem.de/besuchen), and it seems to lighten all text (not sure about the other elements) below it. The navigation above doesn't seem to be affected.

You can see it best when comparing the 'h2' "Besuchen Sie uns" with the 'h2' on the [other pages](http://garten-moorriem.de/workshops).

In fact, you can even see it when you load the page. For a brief second, before Google Maps starts loading, the text has the original styling.

Now, I really can't explain this and haven't found anything about it at all. Granted, I don't have much experience with Google Maps, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: looks fine in firefox on all your pages.  Firebug shows the same styles for the h2 tags.  Might be an issue with your testing medium, or you might be staring at it too long, that happens sometimes.

Comment: You are right, the issue doesn't appear on Firefox. It definitely does on Chrome and Safari (Mac OS) though, you can clearly see the change when the page is loading.

Comment: looks the same in IE 10 & Chrome 26... make sure you can replicate the issue on somebody else's PC.  If it is indeed going lighter for some reason you can try to define the font-weight, opacity, & font-color properties in your CSS.

Comment: I can't reproduce on MacOS Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (Official Build 193261)

Comment: Okay, looks like you are right: It seems to be an issue with my setup, sorry everyone. Pretty weird problem to have though, any ideas where it may come from?

Answer (score 0):

Both headers have computed font-weight:300 and color:#414141 and the same computed font-family on Chrome, and there don't appear to be any Google maps introduced style rules that match them.

The header on the map integration page does seem to overlap the map, but there doesn't seem to be any z-index issue.

Comment: Right, the CSS styling looks to be exactly the same, hence my irritation about why it becomes lighter once Google Maps loads. Thanks.